# What is better in terms of sqlite3 performance: delete unneeded row or set it as not needed?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, performance, sqlite

I am writing an iPhone application where the user receives multiple messages from different users. These messages are stored in an sqlite3 database. With time the user might like to delete received messages from one user, but for sure he will continue to receive new messages from that user after deleting the old ones.

Since retrieving the messages will be done using a `SELECT` statement, which scenario is better to use when the user would like to delete the messages (in terms of performance):

1. `DELETE` all the old messages normally and continue to retrieve the new ones using a statement like: `SELECT Messages FROM TableName WHERE UserID = (?)`
2. Add a field to the table of type `INTEGER` and upon the `DELETE` request set this field to 1 and after that retrieve the new messages using a statement like: `SELECT Messages FROM TableName WHERE UserID = (?) AND IsDeleted = 0`

One more thing, if scenario 1 is used (normal `DELETE`) will this cause any fragmentation of the database file on the disk?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using scenario 1 is much better, since both `SELECT` and `DELETE` in SQL operate at the same level of speed and scenario 1 will grant you not having dangling tuples (Unwanted Rows) in your database.

If you are wishing to perform data backup after any deletion process so scenario 2 is a must but you have to take into consideration the growing size of your database which leads to a slower performance in future.

Finally I would like to add that performing deleting operations on a database would not cause any fragmentation issues since most of databases have fragmentation and optimizing tools in their engines.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a pretty lousy database if `DELETE` didn't work well. In absence of evidence to the contrary, I'd assume you are safe to delete as normal. The database's entire raison d'être is to make these sorts of operations efficient.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer but this raises another question. I noticed that some applications do keep the messages after the user delete them. Do you think they have their own reasons for that and it has nothing to do with performance?

Comment: I can't speculate about apps I've never seen. For that matter I have no idea if those apps' authors even cared about performance or reliability at all. You shouldn't base your designs on their implementations unless you actually know why they made the choices they did.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO if you don't use DELETE, after a while the db will get bigger and bigger, thus making each SELECT less and less efficient.
therefore i figure that deleting rows that will never be used again is more efficient.